# Unable to add an item into the cart for 2nd time using script

Tags: jmeter

I have added an item to my cart using the script but the problem I'm facing is, unable to add the same item more than 1 time.

if the cart is empty, the item is getting added but when the cart contains the item already the number is not getting increased.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to check the headers that are being passed and post request for second iteration.

Comment: I have checked all the parameters and I'm still having the same issue. im unable to find which header I should check